# tkinter label is not showing properly in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Look at the codes!

```
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
labelText = StringVar()
label = Label(frame, textvariable=labelText)
labelText.set("Connecting to the server...")



def welcome_note():
    time.sleep(5)
    labelText.set("Welcome!")

welcome_note()

label.pack()
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When executing the code it should be as "connecting server" then after 5 seconds it should show "welcome"

But it is executing only "welcome" after  5 seconds...

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `after` to call `welcome_note` after 5 seconds

```
def welcome_note():
    labelText.set("Welcome!")

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
labelText = StringVar()
label = Label(frame, textvariable=labelText)
labelText.set("Connecting to the server...")
label.pack()
frame.pack()
# Calls welcome_note after 5 seconds
root.after(5000, welcome_note)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here this should fix your problem. It happened because your label didn't know about the updated information. So adding these lines will show the changes.

Use this [link](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm) for more information.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)

labelText = StringVar()

labelText.set("Connecting to the server...")

label = Label(frame, textvariable=labelText)


label.pack() # ADD THIS
frame.pack() # ADD THIS
label.update() # ADD THIS



def welcome_note():
    time.sleep(5)
    labelText.set("Welcome!")
    label.pack()
    frame.pack()

welcome_note()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: May I know, why `label.update_idletasks()` is added?

Comment: Hey Komal I forgot to change it. Please check the updated code.